# Unity What happens when a device doesn't support your texture size?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What happens when I have an 8K texture for a background in my 2D game when the device that's playing the game doesn't support that texture size.

For instance, what if I have an 8k texture for a background and I try to play the game on an iPhone 5SE (which only supports 4096x4096 textures)?

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted.  Happy to add more information if requested.

Comment: I am not sure offhand what will happen, but presumably either the texture doesn't display or the game crashes. An easy solution for this is to enable mipmaps. Also, you can check the device's maximum supported texture size using `SystemInfo.maxTextureSize`. As far as the downvote, it looks like nearly every single question with the Unity3d tag has 1 downvote, so maybe someone with a lot of rep is DVing every single question that gets posted. You may get a better response at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As an aside, an 8k texture is going to eat up a lot of memory and massively increase your build size.

Comment: So this is for a 2D game, so I'm not sure a mipsmap will help since the distance to the sprites from the camera doesn't really change.  It's a 4K game so the backgrounds are sometimes >4k if the camera needs to pan.  Maybe I can just cut my backgrounds up and stitch them together.

Comment: Mipmaps will still help because on a lower resolution screen, the engine will use the mipmap that is most appropriate for the screen resolution. There is no point in using 4k textures on devices that don't have 4k screens; it's just going to hurt your performance and possibly cause crashes.

Comment: Mipmaps will work for 2D - it depends on the size of the object projected on the screen, not on 3D.